# Find document and use its contents to update it in one atomic operation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, atomic

I have to carry out certain multi-step operations on a set of documents in MongoDB. For instance, my documents each have two sub-documents in them like:

```
{
    "history": [

    ],
    "preview": {
        "title": "This is the preview title",
        "subtitle": "This is a new field"
    },
    "live": {
        "title": "This is the live title"
    }
}
```

I have to find the document, do a diff between the preview and live states, push the diff into history and copy preview into live. How can I do a multi-step operation like this in MongoDB in an atomic way so the data doesn't change mid-operation?

The only thing I can think of is setting a flag on the document using findAndModify to prevent updates in between and then removing the flag with the final update call. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

I should point out that sometimes, I need to publish multiple items in one-go so  performance is important to me.

Comment: Find the document, do all modifications in memory and update it. Single document operations are atomic. You can also bulk several updates together

Comment: I was under the impression that single operations are atomic as in there can't be two simultaneous writes on the same document. However, my question is not about a single operation. It does a find operation, then it does some stuff on the data and then it updates. I don't think Mongo locks the document in between my find and update. How's it even going to know that I am going to update? Could you please clarify? Thank you.